# Storing data in FIWARE Object Storage

Tags: fiware

I'm building an application that stores files into the FIWARE Object Storage. **I don't quite understand what is the correct way of storing files into the storage.**

The code python code snippet below taken from the [Object Storage - User and Programmers Guide](https://forge.fiware.org/plugins/mediawiki/wiki/fiware/index.php/Object_Storage_-_User_and_Programmers_Guide#Example_Python) shows 2 ways of doing it:

```
def store_text(token, auth, container_name, object_name, object_text):
   headers = {"X-Auth-Token": token}

   # 1. version
   #body = '{"mimetype":"text/plain", "metadata":{}, "value" : "' + object_text + '"}'

   # 2. version
   body = object_text

   url = auth + "/" + container_name + "/" + object_name

   return swift_request('PUT', url, headers, body)
```

The **1. version** confuses me, because when I first looked at the only Node.js module (repo: [fiware-object-storage](https://github.com/arvidkahl/fiware-object-storage)) that works with Object Storage, it seemed to use **1. version**. As the module was making calls to the old (v.1.1) API version instead of the presumably newest (v.2.0), referencing to the python example, not sure if that is an outdated version of doing it or not.

---

As I played more with the module, realised it didn't work and the code for it was a total mess. So I forked the project and quickly understood that I will need rewrite it form the ground up, taking the above mention python example from the usage guide as an reference. [Link to my repo](https://github.com/renarsvilnis/fiware-object-storage).

As of writing this the only methods that aren't implement is the object storage (PUT) and object fetching (GET).

---

Had some addition questions about the Object Storage which I sent to fiware-lab-help@lists.fiware.org, but haven't heard anything back so asking them here.

1. Haven't got much experience with writing API libraries. **Should I need to worry about auth token expiring?** I presume it is not needed to make a new authentication, every time we interact with storage. The authentication should happen once when server is starting-up (we create a instance) and it internally keeps it. **Should I implement some kind of mechanism that refreshes the token?**
2. **Does the tenant id change?** From the quote below is presume that getting a tenant I just a one time deal, then later you can use it in the config to make less authentication calls.

> A valid token is required to access an object store. This section
>   describes how to get a valid token assuming an identity management
>   system compatible with OpenStack Keystone is being used. If the
>   username, password and tenant details are known, only step 3 is
>   required. source

3. **During the authentication when fetching tenants how should I select the "right" one?** For now i'm just taking the first one similar as the example code does.
4. **Is it true that a object storage container belongs to only a single region?**

Comment: Hi Renārs, I'm the main developer of WireCloud, and I was reading your question because you used the `fiware-wirecloud` tag, but I don't see any relationship. I recommend you to remove the `fiware-wirecloud` tag ;-)

Comment: Sorry about it, fixed it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my troubles and created the NPM module that works with the FIWARE Object Storage: https://github.com/renarsvilnis/fiware-object-storage-ge

Answer (score 0):

Use only what you call version 2. Ignore your version 1. It is commented out in the example. It should be removed from the documentation.

(1) The token will be valid for some period of time. This could be an hour or a day, depending on the setup. This period of time should be specified in the token that is returned by the authentication service. The token needs to be periodically refreshed.

(2) The tenant id does not change.

(3) Typically only one tenant id is returned. It is possible, however, that you were assigned more than one id, in which case you have to pick which one you are currently using. Containers typically belong to a single tenant and are not shared between tenants.

(4) Containers are typically limited to a single region. This may change in the future when multi-region support for a container is added to Swift.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But going with the 2. version if I store an image in the Object Storage how should I save it? base64? And when fetching it back how can I get that it is an image, for example the container may contain jpegs and png. How do I specify the mime time the object will be when uploading?

Comment: Upload it with the PUT request in its ordinary binary format, and use the "Content-Type" header to specify the mime type.

Comment: But when fetching the file presumably I need to know what will be the headers I'm willing to recieve? Save the mimetype alongside the filename in database?

Comment: Also looking at some library code found it used to use application/cdmi-object contenty type header when uploading.